# element animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i saw an effect in  iconArchive site and i don't no how to apply it if one of you help me to get the idea with small example this will be nice.
under this link :http://www.iconarchive.com/search?q=share&page=3 if you go over the heart img then a copy of it will move to the bottom and add the icon you have selected. i have no idea how to start for that reason i don't have any code .
i think they use java script +jquery+ css to do it.

Answer (score 2):

The jQuery `animate` function can do this neatly: http://jsfiddle.net/bX6Uk/.

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    $('#div').animate({
        top: 300,
        left: 10,
    }, 'slow');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the specific effect on your example page you should check out the [jQuery UI Transfer effect](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Transfer).